# Will snowflake unload to S3 fail if assume role credentials expire

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to unload huge chunks of data from snowflake into S3. Currently says that I can use the copy into feature, where I use sts assume role temporary creds to do this unload.

The problem I am wondering is: If I specified my assume role duration to be 12 hours, but unload takes longer than that. Would the unload fail then?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#additional-cloud-provider-parameters

Comment: I would assume it will fail indeed.

Comment: If its taking you more than 12 hours, you may also want to consider using a larger warehouse.  The larger the warehouse, the more threads will be used to generate files to S3, the faster it will run.